# Use runtime environment variables in Nuxt in modules

Tags: nuxt.js

I recently stumbled into an issue with Nuxt, I tried using publicRuntimeConfig with the environment variable and I also tried to use nuxt-env (which can't be used in modules and I need it in the i18n module). It seems that the runtime configuration is using environment variables in the build as it's working well in local environment and the environment variables are well defined in the staging container, but for some reason $config.baseUrl is undefined.

How can we use the container environment variables to use them in modules and other places knowing that nuxt-env $env is not defined yet in other modules and that runtime configurations are set during the build phase?